# How to bind html data using Polymer?

Tags: html, polymer

Here's *Mr. Polymer*

```
Polymer({
  is: 'mr-polymer',

  properties: {
    headline: {
      type: String,
      value: 'keep <span class="highlight">stronger</span>'
    }
  }
}
```

Mr. Polymer has a headline containing html tags.

Then Mr. Polymer is going to talk the headline in his template :

```
<template>
  <p id="talk">[[headline]]</p>
</template>
```

**"oh no ! Mr. Polymer.. what are you saying ?"**

it doesn't process the html tags..

Is there a way to bind html data ?

Comment: It seems the framework does execute a simple print out and not an `eval()`. If you found no way out you can use eval() afterwards. I know is not a good way...

Comment: If this question refers to Polymer 1.0, then I don't think it can be a duplicate of the question @Maria references because that question is almost one year old so it must have been for v0.5 or earlier. As we know, answers for v1.0 won't *necessarily* apply to v0.5 and vice versa. 발렌탕, could you please confirm that this question applies to Polymer 1.0?

Comment: @Mowzer, what you can do in 0.5 can be done in 1.0, that duplicate is consistent to my question. I managed printing html data using an echo Polymer as suggested in the link found from the duplicate. It answered my question. thanks